# How to Refer back to Its Label from Input Field?

Tags: html, angular

Using `for` we can link a label with a control say `<input>`, so clicks on the label sets focus into the control. Great.

This maybe a silly question. What about the other way? I want to be able to tell which label this input is associated with. For example

```
<form [formGroup]="MyForm">
<label id="RemoteLabel" for="FarAwayControl">Far Away</label>
...
<input id="FarAwayControl" formControlName="FarAwayControl">
```

So far don't see any direct property of `this.MyForm.controls.FarAwayControl` link back to label, maybe only option is to traverse back to parent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that [`<input />` elements have a `labels` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/labels) that returns a `NodeList` of associated `<label>` elements.  From the MDN page:

> The `HTMLInputElement.labels` read-only property returns a `NodeList` of the `<label>` elements associated with the `<input>` element, if the element is not `hidden`. If the element has the type hidden, the property returns `null`.

You can see it here in action:

```js
const myInput = document.querySelector('#username');
const myInputLabel = myInput.labels[0];
console.log(`My input is labelled as "${myInputLabel.textContent}".`);
```

```html
<label for="username">Click me</label>
<input type="text" id="username">
```

Please note that this feature is not supported in Internet Explorer (if that matters to you).